# How to increment a column value by 1 for selected rows in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table which contains the columns `id`, `name`, `item` and `counter`.Now I want to increment the `counter` value by **1** for those rows that the user belongs to.

I tried doing something like this but I get syntax error

```
UPDATE Items set counter = counter + 1 WHERE users = 'Tony';
```

This should increment the `counter` value by **1** for all the rows that the user **Tony** belongs to.Something like

**initial**

```
id | name | item    | counter
1  | Tony  | car    | 1
2  | Tony  | bike   | 1
3  | Ray   | car    | 1
4  | Ray   | bike   | 1
5  | Tony  | cycle  | 1
```

**final**

```
id | name | item    | counter
1  | Tony  | car    | 2
2  | Tony  | bike   | 2
3  | Ray   | car    | 1
4  | Ray   | bike   | 1
5  | Tony  | cycle  | 2
```

But I get syntax error for my query.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the error message you're receiving

Comment: Perhaps because your table has a column called `name` but not one called `user`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh my bad!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` query contains `users` instead of `name`.

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=796dafc63bd6fae39f4d622e1f417e74)

```
UPDATE Items set counter = counter + 1 WHERE name = 'Tony';
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably column name was wrong. try this:

```
UPDATE Items set counter = counter + 1 WHERE name= 'Tony';
```

Answer (score -1):

FOR rowdata1 IN

```
    select   employee_id, accrual_group_code, accrual_type, start_date,accru_date from z_123  where (doc_id =0 or doc_id is null ) order by accru_date
            LOOP
                            employeeId   = rowdata1.employee_id;
                            accrualgroupcode   = rowdata1.accrual_group_code;
                            accrualtype   = rowdata1.accrual_type;
                            accrudate   = rowdata1.accru_date;
                            select (cast(date_trunc('month', accrudate::date) as date) - interval '1 month')::date into startdate;

                            update  z_123 set company_id = 2 , doc_id= 2 where employee_id = employeeId
                            and  accrual_group_code = accrualgroupcode and  accrual_type = accrualtype and accru_date = accrudate;                                
            END LOOP;
```